# operator -> or ->* applied to "const std::weak_ptr" instead of to a pointer typeC/C++

Tags: c++, weak-ptr

In a lambda function, instead of this, I was trying to use `weak_ptr` to access all member function and variable, but I'm getting this error:

> operator -> or ->* applied to "const std::weak_ptr" instead of to a pointer type

Comment: Does std::weak_ptr have a `const operator->()`? Perhaps you mean to use a (smart) pointer type instead, as the error message says?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::weak_ptr<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) by design safely refers to an object which may or may not still exist. It does not offer `operator->` or `operator*` since you have to make sure the object still exists before you can try to access it.

To access an object referred to by a `std::weak_ptr` you first call `lock()` which returns a `std::shared_ptr`. Then, you need to check if that `std::shared_ptr` refers to an object. If it does, then the object is safe to access and won't be deleted until that returned pointer is destroyed (because there will still exist a `std::shared_ptr` for it). If it doesn't then the `std::weak_ptr` was referring to a destroyed object which you can't access anymore.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Yd4zTfaMa) :

```
#include <memory>

class foo 
{
public:
    void bar(){}
};

void test(std::weak_ptr<foo> ptr)
{
    // Get a shared_ptr
    auto lock = ptr.lock();

    // Check if the object still exists
    if(lock) 
    {
        // Still exists, safe to dereference
        lock->bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `if(auto lock = ptr.lock())` also works.